How to make a Select required in TSX file?
I want a Select component to be required in my app
required option is not accepted by Select component for some reason. As well as required={true}
Error message is:
Property 'required' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Omit<PublicBaseSelectProps<SelectOption, false, GroupBase<SelectOption>>, StateManagedPropKeys> & Partial<...> & StateManagerAdditionalProps<...> & RefAttributes<...>

My design is
                                    <Select
                                        required={true}
                                        placeholder={"Select region"}
                                        value={props.selectedRegion}
                                        options={props.regionsOptions}
                                        className="width-285"
                                        onChange={props.onSelectRegionsOptions}
                                    /> 

Why is it impossible to make a Select component required it React? One other option I found online is to wrap the Select  in FormControl  and make the latter required, but this does not work for my validation, and also does not display required symbol and red text on the component.
This app was not made by me, I got it from another team member. There is no documentation. I just need to make one field required.
What is the solution to this problem?

Based on the prop names, that looks like react-select. It simply doesn't have that prop.

@AKX it is react-select so there's no way to make it required and I have to use a different component? And what is the reason for this component not having a required property?

Well, react-select isn't a regular form field, so the standard HTML required attribute (which prevents the owning form from being submitted) that would apply to <select> wouldn't do a thing, hence it isn't a thing. What would this select being required mean for you and your app?

@AKX well this is a new requirement for this app, this field always has to have a value

What if it doesn't have a value? What should not be allowed?

@AKX yeah now that I think about it better solution is to predefine a default value for this select

It seems like the Select component doesn't support required property as default. In this case, you can make a custom Select component inherited the original Select. I provide sample code for it.
const CustomSelect = ({ required = false, wrapperClass, optionClass, onChange, value, options, selectedOption, placeholder}) => {
    const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsValid(!!selectedOption);
    }. [selectedOption]);

    <div className={wrapperClass}>
        <Select
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={selectedOption}
            options={options}
            className={optionClass}
            onChange={onChange}
        />
        {!isValid && <p className='error-message'>This field is required</p>}
    </div>
}

you can use the required property with the above CustomSelect component. Hope it helps you.

thanks for responding. I beleive this component is customized already: declare type StateManagedSelect = <Option = unknown, IsMulti extends boolean = false, Group extends GroupBase<Option> = GroupBase<Option>>(props: StateManagerProps<Option, IsMulti, Group> & RefAttributes<Select<Option, IsMulti, Group>>) => ReactElement; declare const StateManagedSelect: StateManagedSelect; so how can I add the required prop to this declaration? Thanks again

@EcmaScriptIsMyNativeLanguage Instead of making the Select, from the library you're using, required, they're providing you with a wrapper that wraps around the Select component, and makes the CustomSelect required.

isValid shouldn't be a state atom updated via an effect – const isValid = !!selectedOption; is the correct thing to do.

In short: you can't make a react-select <Select> required like you can with regular form elements.
react-select's <Select> does not have a required prop, because it's not a regular HTML form element (which is where required would have an effect on the validation of the owning form), and such a prop would have no effect.
What should happen when there is no value for a react-select depends entirely on your particular app, and you'll need to do that validation "by hand". For instance, you could set the aria-invalid prop on the field, and disable your form's submit button.
